# Using YARA in windows machine WAZUH

Tags: windows, yara

Is there any Yara integration with WAZUH tutorial for windows I can refer to. Since running the yara.exe didnt have any effect on my windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a blog post explaining how to detect LockBit 3.0 which covers Yara configuration on Windows as well.

https://wazuh.com/blog/detecting-lockbit-3-0-ransomware-with-wazuh/

Hope this helps!